# Remove comma between the quotes only in a comma delimited file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, gsub

This is my input:

```
"a","b","c","d",",","f"
```

Expected output:

```
"a","b","c","d","","f"
```

Basically for every occurring  `","`,  I want to replace it with `""`.
Also I want to run the command for *n* number of lines of for *n* number of fields.

I have tried the below command

awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", "", $i) } 1' infile

But it removes double quotes too but that is not what I require...
I require double quotes also

Comment: Stack Overflow is no "Post your question and get code"-site... Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @Seth  I have tried below command but it reomves double quotes and I dnt want to remove it..                        awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", "", $i) } 1' infile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use AWK or SED to remove commas between quotation marks from a CSV file? (BASH)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620713/should-i-use-awk-or-sed-to-remove-commas-between-quotation-marks-from-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
echo '"a","b","c","d",",","f"'  | sed 's/,",",/,"",/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this works:

```
echo '"a","b","c","d",",","f"' | awk '{sub(/\42,\42,\42/,"\42,\42\42")}1'
"a","b","c","d","","f"
```